# Error forbidden 403 with android firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have developed an app that uses firebase authentication and successfully created accounts and logged in many times. But today, I tried to log in to my app and found this error.
P.S: I use Cloudflare Warp to connect to my internet.

com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvt: Failed to parse error for string [      Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1      *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}

**403.** That’s an error.

Your client does not have permission to get URL `/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword` from this server.  That’s all we know.] with exception: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject